# Azure AD Profile image to Slack

Tags: azure-active-directory, slack, slack-api

We are using Azure AD as well as Slack today. For most services we are using SCIM o provision users. All users have a profile image in Azure AD. As far as I understand it Slack does not support profile image when using SCIM as they only have scim 1.1. So is there some way or have anyone solved this in another way? My knowledge of writing advanced script and using apis is limited. I want my Azure user imaged replicated to Slack.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't supported or possible to transmit pictures using Azure AD's SCIM provisioning service today. It's a feature we've seen requested before and we're working on solving the problem.

If you are going to attempt to populate the picture in Slack today, it will have to be done via some form of scripting/automation on your end calling an API endpoint of Slack's that allows for upload of profile pictures.